# How to fill object JS inside new?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I have defination of object like:

```
let translateObj: ITranslate;
```

I tried to initializae this like corresponding interface:

```
let obj = new translateObj = {
          keyTranslate: 'subjectId',
          outName: 'name'
        }
```

It does not work...Can I use this suffix?

I tried this:

```
export class MapperServiceArray<T> implements IMapperServiceArray<T> {
  public constructor(public key: string | number, public translate?: ITranslate) {
}
```

I create instance like this:

```
 let mapperArray = new MapperServiceArray<ISubjectBase>('subjectId', {
          keyTranslate: 'subjectId',
          outName: 'name'
        });
```

Comment: Is `ITranslate` a class or interface?

Comment: This is interface

Comment: Look my updated question

Comment: Could you post what the `ITranslate` interface looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you use `new translateObj` ?
If you declare an interface and want your object to be of type of that interface, you need just set the type to it and initialize an object without `new`.

```
let obj: ITranslate = {
    keyTranslate: 'subjectId',
    outName: 'name'
}
```

Comment: But how to pass this object as parameter in function? I mean this: `function a (new {properies...})`

Comment: In which function ?

Comment: yourFunction(obj)

Comment: Will it work as you suggest? I dont need to initialize this using `new`?

Comment: No, if the `ITranslate` is an interface, not an class. Try it